# How to use MSAL's loginRedirect in an Ngrx Effect?

Tags: angular, ngrx, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm wondering if there is a way to use Msal angular's loginRedirect(): void function instead of loginPopup(): Promise in an Ngrx Effect.

I'm able to use the loginPopup() but due to the void return type of loginRedirect() it breaks my ngrx effects chain. I can't use the loginPopup() function due to the issues with popups on mobile devices.

Here is the code that works for loginPopup(): Promise

```
@Effect()
  msalAuthLogin$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(MsalAuthActionTypes.Login),
    switchMap(() =>
      this.msalAuthService.loginPopup().pipe(
        map(id_token => new AcquireTokenSilent()),
        catchError(error => of(new LoginFail({ error })))
      )
    )
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing '{dispatch: false}' through your decorator like this:

```
@Effect({dispatch: false})
```

When writing an effect that does not dispatch an action, you need to be explicit about it.  If youre not, your application will try to both subscribe to and dispatch the same action - crashing your browser

Answer (score 0):

I discuss some of them in [Start using ngrx/effects for this](https://timdeschryver.dev/posts/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this)

Dialog:

```
@Effect()
openDialog = this.actions.pipe(
  ofType(LoginActionTypes.OpenLoginDialog),
  exhaustMap(_ => {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(LoginDialog);
    return dialogRef.afterClosed();
  }),
  map((result: any) => {
    if (result === undefined) {
      return new CloseDialog();
    }
    return new LoginDialogSuccess(result);
  }),
);
```

Navigation:

```
@Effect({ dispatch: false })
logOut = this.actions.pipe(
  ofType(ActionTypes.LogOut),
  tap([payload, username] => {
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  })
)
```